# Dialed names are not shown (htc u11)

Tags: phone-app, google-contacts, htc-u11

Contact name is stored in Google. But when I dial it, and finish the call, it shows only the number without name as if I don't have the name stored. And it only happens with my new stored numbers, and since one week till now.

How to solve this?

Comment: Do the numbers show up when you search for them in your contacts app?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have saved the same number in two or more contacts. Either that was by you or it was caused when importing contacts from another source. I had similar problems and it was solved when I deleted duplicates.